# What is the best way to notify the developer (myself) of errors during production?

Tags: c#, windows, issue-tracking, feedback

I'm starting to write production software (just for myself, not for a company with a pre-set mode of operations for this). I want to find a way to send a message from my users to me (the developer) whenever a critical error occurs.

For example, I write to files on the system very frequently, so I want to know if there was an issue with writing to one system vs. another or if something displayed incorrectly.

The only way I can think of doing this seems dumb to even say, but I know how to send emails from my program, so I could create a log file and have it automatically email it to myself when the user gets a connection, but that seems so far from ideal. Alternatively, I could run a server on my computer and use sockets to send data, but that isn't ideal either.

In case it helps, I'm developing for UWP on Windows. I know that you can use the Feedback Hub to send developers feedback, but I am talking about a small background bug that I want to know about but might not have caught on my machine.

Comment: You've already got some feasible mechanisms. Don't forget to request consent from the user, as siphoning out data (even if only stack traces) from user devices without explicit consent is at least bad style and probably even illegal depending on your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, some of which you've already identified, from simple "low-tech" approaches like automatically emailing an attachment, to using existing app analytics and monitoring services like AppCenter, to writing custom telemetry and reporting code. There are advantages and disadvantages to each.

1. Emailing the exception details and log to a predetermined address isn't a *bad* idea. It's simple, uses well-known protocols and doesn't require any back-end investment beyond an inbox. It's certainly a good place to start if you want something out there quickly, but it has drawbacks: SMTP's port 25 might be blocked on customer machines or networks, and the delivery method - a simple text file - means you have to manually manage these error dumps, store them somewhere, remember which came from which customer, etc.
2. Monitoring services like Microsoft's [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/) offer a wide set of services for you to use. You have client libraries you can include in your app and use to automatically report errors to a central repository. This can include a lot more than just critical error logs: you can get any analytics you care to about how your users use your app, and the service gives you options like push notifications for errors, tools to aggregate and analyze the data, and so on. The drawbacks are complexity (you have to integrate with a not necessarily trivial 3rd party system) and possibly cost, as some of these services might have a free tier, but are usually subscription-based.
3. Custom monitoring and telemetry. Similar to #2, except instead of using an off-the-shelf managed solution, you write your own basic reporting service on the web, and instead of just emailing a log, your client connects to your service and sends any data you care to send. The advantages include customizability (store just the data you need, and have it available anywhere), but the drawbacks include a lot more work (custom code on the client and also the custom back-end components), maintaining the back-end server (easiest is a simple cloud service, but that also costs time and money), and opening up to potential vulnerabilities.